# Make element expand width minus margin-right

Tags: html, css

Based on a centered container, is it possible with CSS only to make another element aligned to the left expanding the right border of this centered container?

The second element should expand until the red dashed line.

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: calc(100% + 3rem);
  background: none;
  border-right: 1px dashed red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.grey {
   background: #ccc;
   padding: 1rem;
}

.stretch-row-left {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grey"></div>
<div class="stretch-row-left grey"></div>
```

While I could achieve this with some Javascript, I am wondering if there is a CSS only approach.

Desired effect achieved with JS:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const stretchBlock = document.querySelector('.stretch-row-left');

function returnWidth(){
    return stretchBlock.style.maxWidth = 'calc('+(container.clientWidth + container.offsetLeft) + 'px'+ ' - 0.5rem)';
}

returnWidth();

window.addEventListener("resize", returnWidth);
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: calc(100% + 3rem);
  background: none;
  border-right: 1px dashed red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.grey {
   background: #ccc;
   padding: 1rem;
}

.stretch-row-left {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grey"></div>
<div class="stretch-row-left grey"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add parent div  and use `position: absolute` and `right: 0` or that's something you do not want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some calculations to deduct half of the space outside 500px from its width:

```
width: calc(100% - calc(calc(100% - 500px) / 2));
```

In a sense, though, you're basically trying to replicate the benefits of a proper grid without the grid. Three-column layout would get you there, too.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: calc(100% + 3rem);
  background: none;
  border-right: 1px dashed red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.grey {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.stretch-row-left {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: calc(100% - calc(calc(100% - 500px) / 2));
}
```

```html
<div class="container grey"></div>
<div class="stretch-row-left grey"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

margin-right can do the job `margin-right: max(0px,50% - 500px/2)`. I am using `max()` to make sure we always get a positive value so `0px` will be used when the width is smaller than `500px`

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: calc(100% + 3rem);
  background: none;
  border-right: 1px dashed red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.grey {
   background: #ccc;
   padding: 1rem;
}

.stretch-row-left {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-right: max(0px,50% - 500px/2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container grey"></div>
<div class="stretch-row-left grey"></div>
```